# Create S3 bucket first or Cloudfront Distribution?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

When I initially setup Cloudfront, I created the Cloudfront Distribution first.  It was very confusing because at the time, I knew nothing about the S3 Management Console.  The S3 MC is where you create buckets.  Cloudfront request one of these buckets when you are creating the Distribution.

For someone setting up a brand new S3 account, what is the correct order: S3 Bucket then Cloudfront Distribution or vice versa?

When creating a Distribution, is there only thing required the "Origin Domain Name"?  I've included a screenshot of the upper half Distribution setup form.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For someone setting up a brand new S3 account, what is the correct order:

If your CloudFront content is to be coming from S3, setup your S3 bucket first

> When creating a Distribution, is there only thing required the "Origin Domain Name"

Potentially yes, the defaults for the remaining settings will be good enough in many cases. Here's a step by step if you want to [set your own CNAME](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/amazon-cloudfront-how-to-setup-cloudfront-to-work-with-s3/)

The CloudFront distribution may take 20 minutes to activate, and then use the S3 Management console as required to set permissions and possibly other options on the S3 bucket.

Good luck!